# How to : Angularjs route refresh

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ngroute

I trying to make an application that contains multiple views as template. The templates are under the `js/app/pages/` folder. And I have 2 templates to show and route. My routing section is:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/Page', {
        templateUrl: 'js/app/pages/Page.html',
        controller: 'pageController',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .when('/Settings', {
        templateUrl: 'js/app/pages/Settings.html',
        controller: 'settingsController',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .when('/Admin', {
        templateUrl: 'js/app/pages/Admin.html',
        controller: 'adminController',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/Page'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

And my html file contains

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<div ng-view></div>
```

Menu div contains menu elements that route me between the pages. For example, when I run this site on browser, URL will be localhost/Page, and when I click the settings button URL change with localhost/Settings. But when I press the <kbd>F5</kbd> button in my keyboard. Page gives me error `The resource cannot be found.`.

I search on the internet "how to refresh routing page in angularjs" and find some solutions but I couldn't make them work for me. I tried `$route.reload()` and `$routeUpdate()` method but that does not work for me. Maybe I'm wrong in something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I couldn't manage refresh with ngRoute. Then i convert it into ui-router. I declare the states by urls. And the refresh is working. Thanks for comments and answers. Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache server this should work run this in terminal

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart
```

works for me

Comment: No, i'm using iis. Not apache server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you "reload a page", you whole app will reinit again.  That means if you are not on the main page, and the sub route you are at missing some data, you will likely get an error.

You should look into resolve attribute for routes, so for example,

```
.when('/Settings', {
        templateUrl: 'js/app/pages/Settings.html',
        controller: 'settingsController',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        resolve: {
            resourceone: function(){return whatsneeedtoberesolvehere;}
        }
    })
```

that way no matter where your app is reloaded, it will have the necessary data to boot the page

Comment: what is whatsneedtoberesolvehere? is this a function that resolve which url i'm in? or not? can you add some more detail please?

Comment: you should resolve whatever resource you are getting the error for here, as in resourceone above.  then you can inject that into any controller and use it as you wish in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you are pressing F5 from keyboard, it is hitting to your server for that page, not angular because you don't have any `#` sign between your URL. For angular, URL should be like as - `localhost/#/Page`

Comment: I didn't understand the mean of "#" sign. Can you add some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

## Use html5mode

A great article about it [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)

to init its very simple

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    // other routes here

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

Comment: oh you're already using it, well the article is still good. best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the # in URL, you don't have to put extra effort to manage reloads etc. you can think a "#" in URL represent a specific state in single page application.

Otherwise it can be managed by module rewriting, that map the url with hashed version URL internally for AngularJs app.

Comment: you mean the url like 'localhost/#/Page' or 'localhost/#/Settings'. is this right?